# GWT+Eclipse without GWT_CONTAINER

Tags: gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

## The situation

I'm using GWT with Eclipse and Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE).
Gradle is the build tool and the Eclipse classpath is generated by Gradle. As I have no "com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER" on my classpath, GPE always shows the error "The project 'Test' does not have any GWT SDKs on its build path" and the Console sometimes prints "GWT SDK not installed.".
Annother effect is that Eclipse doesn't let me GWT-compile the project (but running dev mode works fine). But that one is ok for me, as I compile using Gradle.

## Things I'm aware of

I know that I can exclude all GWT depedencies from the Eclipse classpath and add the container through Gradle (I did that for other projects). But as I can't enforce the GWT version provided by Eclipse (I can only specify the SDK's name in the classpath by adding the suffix "/" to the conatiner), I think thats an ugly solution. Another point is that the GPE update site only lists the latest GWT version available. There's no way to automatically install an older version (yes you can provide one externally).

When using GPE together with Maven and m2e it simply works: GPE links no real SDK for Maven projects but there's a link to the "com.google.gwt" group in the local Maven repository. But that's magic I can't use because:

1. Gradle's local repository format is different to Maven's
2. This logic is implemented in the plugin "com.google.gdt.eclipse.maven" and I can't use that without adding a pom.xml to the project

## The questions

1. Is there a possibility to deactivate this nasty error without loosing other GPE features?
2. Is it possible to do something similar to what GPE+m2e does without
   creating my own Eclipse plugin?
3. Am I right that excluding the jars and adding the container is the only viable solution by now?

Comment: Item 1 is possible by opening **Preferences->Google->Errors/Warnings** and changing the severity level of the "Missing SDK".

Comment: Thanks Boris, I only searched at project level.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this library to launch with custom classpath and other settings: https://github.com/eclecticlogic/gwt-launcher